# How to convince user to connect to domain?

Tags: windows, domain, workgroup

Some of my users (whom are also board members and managers in the company) do not want to log to the domain (they use the workgroup)

How do I convince them?
Pros and cons please

Comment: I would try asking them why they don't want to log into the domain, and then working with them to address their needs and concerns.

Comment: also, you may want to look into how they are going about their business without being logged to the domain, as this may be a security / policy loophole. Tie as many services as possible into the domain (which is usually a good idea anyway, printing, proxy servers etc.) and you'll be in a stronger position.

Comment: Are these company issued/owned computers? If yes, how did they get them as non-domain members? How did they get local user names and passwords?

Comment: The computers are company owned. We are not the most organized, but it's a software company. Ans as you can guess, each of them devs is messing around. Point is, I need to convince them that staying off the domain is bad for the company and bad for them.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a technical issue but a managerial one - let the IT manager (or if that's you the CEO) **MANDATE** they they not only address this problem but they adhere to a whole series of usage policies - if they're refusing to do this one simple thing lord knows what else they're doing.

Comment: On the other hand: Why do they have to connect to the domain? If they don't want to and don't have to then it is not necessary, is it?

Comment: One reason - group policies and all the goodness that comes with that, security, updates, licence adherence etc.